# R: Predefined background colors for a matrix

Tags: r, latex, knitr

On a report I would like to represent a state change matrix between dates.
Lets say I have a matrix like this:

```
B = data.frame(c(0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0,5,0,0,5,0,0,5,0,0,0), nrow=4, ncol=4) 
dimnames(B)<-list(c("A","B","C","D"),c("D","C","B","A"))
```

B would be something like this:

```
  D C B A
A 0 0 0 5
B 0 0 5 0
C 0 5 0 0
D 5 0 0 0
```

Any change from D->C->B->A would be an improvement and changes from A->B->C->D would be a problem.

I would like to have this represented (will be used in a knitr document) with a neutral background color in the diagonal (the 5's in my matrix) and then green at the right of the diagonal (improvement) and red to the left (problem). Any suggestion how to do this? The numbers should appear anyway and shouldn't change the background colors.

Any further suggestions on alternatives to represent this are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New version without a 'hand-made' matrix for the `image` command

```
## the input data as vector (as in the question)
## size has to be a square number
values <- c(0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0,5,0,0,5,0,0,5,0,0,0)

size <- sqrt(length(values))
a <- matrix(0, nrow=size, ncol=size)
a[lower.tri(a)] <- +1
a[upper.tri(a)] <- -1
image(a,col=c('red','transparent','green'),xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab='',ylab='')
text(rep(seq(1,0,len=size),len=size*size),rep(seq(0,1,len=size),each=size),values)
```

Comment: How do you create the matrix values? by hand?

Comment: @agstudy: yes, but I updated the answer with an non handmade matrix.

Comment: @Jörg Yes, you did perfectly! The solution works great. Thank you. I'm getting my "matrix" value from a xtabs done to a rather large dataframe and I'll end up with a variable size matrix(8x8 or 9x9). Any suggestion on how to use that xtabs output with your solution?

Comment: I surely miss something ... the OP is not clear with "Any change from D->C->B->A "...

Comment: @JörgMäder. You are too fast for me :). You updated the answer when I was still thinking how to ask you what you replied! Thanks again!

Comment: @agstudy D to C is a good state change (or D to B or B to A) thats why the "positive" coloring. Sorry if wasn't clear.